# How to display value as editable textarea under div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<select name="value" id="value" class="inputbox" size="1">
<option value=""> - Select Value- </option>
<option value="red">lamp1</option>
<option value="orange">lamp2</option>
<option value="green">lamp3</option>
</select>
<div id="valuePreview">displays value here</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#value").change(function () {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("textarea#valuePreview").html($(this).val(result.valuePreview));
    });
});
```

I try to make the result under `id=valuepreview` as 'red', 'orange' and 'green' editable like `<textarea>` in HTML. My jQuery is not good (I'm a newbie) because the script above doesn't work in any browsers, can you guys advise how I can fix the jQuery problems?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="valuePreview" contenteditable="true">....</div>
```

Also I think you want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#value").change(function () {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("div#valuePreview").html(src);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/5RuTq/

Comment: Thanks Neal. This is what I'm looking for. It works on IE7/8, FF, Opera and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$('select').change(
    function(){
        $('#valuePreview').text($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8pYTJ/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer David Thomas. I believe Neal answer is the one that I look for. However, thank you.

Comment: You're *more* than welcome =) Incidentally, if Neal's answer was what you needed, I'd suggest accepting that answer (click the check-mark below the vote-count).